# How to make Max Width and Height work with Jquery ImgViewer Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I am using the ImgViewer v.6 for zooming images (w/IE8 support).

It works fine when the image is wider than taller. However, when an image is taller, the entire height does not display in the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/wmx05cty/

In this fiddle, you can see the top image has some of its height clipped off.

I need to fill up the viewport with as much of the image as possible without stretching the image. The image needs to remain proportional. The width should be 100%, and a tall image should have the height fit the viewport height as well. The tall image needs to be centered horizontally and its entire width and height visible initially.

So, I modified the plugin to detect the height, and if taller, set the height to the viewport's height.

```
  if (height > width) {
        var ratio = $view.height() / height;
        ih = $view.height();
        iw = width * ratio;  
  }
```

This works except that the image is not centered. The math on the viewport and image are not quite right.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/qontbr9e/

I need a way to center both images in their containers, display the entire width so that it fills the container, and if it is a taller image, resize it so that the height fits in the container on init.

This is a dynamic application, so I cannot apply styles to individual images. The same script needs to work on both images using the same css. I must use the v.6 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**: Cleaned up the answer.

So, this solution is a bit messy but it works:

[Fiddle for centered only on x](http://jsfiddle.net/qontbr9e/8/)

[Fiddle for centered on both x and y](http://jsfiddle.net/qontbr9e/10/)

In the widget constructor:

```
this.$oldview = $img.parent(); //store original container element
```

Then in the update method:

```
$(this.view).position({
                    my: "left top",
                    at: "left top",
                    of: this.$oldview
                });
```

This shifts the viewport back into position (for some reason the code you added makes the viewport go to absolute(0,0)).

At the end of update, I add an offset to `zLeft`.

```
var offsetx = //offset need to horizontally center image
    (this.$oldview.width() / 2) -
    (((this.zimg).width() / 2) / zoom);

$(this.zimg).css({ //center image
    left: zLeft + offsetx + "px"
});
```

And this at the start of update because it was misbehaving when zoomed out all the way:

```
if (zoom < 1) {
    this.options.zoom = 1;
    zoom = 1;
}
```

I also removed the `text-align:center`.I *think* that's all the changes I made.

If you want it centered vertically too, same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/qontbr9e/10/
Same thing but for both x and y:

```
var offsetx = //offset need to horizontally center image
    this.$oldview.width() / 2 -
    (this.zimg).width() / 2 / zoom;
var offsety = //offset need to vertically center image
    this.$oldview.height() / 2 -
    (this.zimg).height() / 2 / zoom;

$(this.zimg).css({ //center image
    left: zLeft + offsetx + "px",
    top: zTop + offsety + "px"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want to stretch your image to take entire div with. If, i am correct, then you can do this with css. Just set width and height to  100%.
Add this class to your css.

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;   
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wmx05cty/4/

/**** EDITED CONTENT ****/

If you only wants to stretch(resize) the image to fit to div, which is greater than div height or width, then use this css.

```
img {
    max-width:100% ;
    max-height:100%;   
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wmx05cty/6/

Hope, it helps.

Comment: it also stretches the other one which was shown correctly

Comment: The image needs to be proportional. Not stretched. I edited the question to make this clearer. The Zoom effect in 6 does not work either. I believe the only way to get what I am after is by modifying the JS.

Answer (score 0):

You need the max width max height and a margin auto auto;

http://jsfiddle.net/wmx05cty/7/

css :

```
    img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin:auto auto;

}
```

Comment: The zoom effect does not work. Try scrolling with mousewheel. Also the image needs to be proportional, not stretched.